# android studio question

Tags: android-studio

Is this right:
first:

```
    -sudo apt-get-repository -y ppa:webupd8team/java

    -sudo apt-get update

    -sudo apt-get install -y oracle-java8-installer
```

than

```
sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0 lib32stdc++6
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6
```

For Install Android Studio:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:paolorotolo/android-studio
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install android-studio
```

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score -1):

The [Github page for that package](https://github.com/paolorotolo/android-studio#32-bit-compatibility-libraries) recommends the following if you can't correctly build a project on Ubuntu amd64:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-i386 lib32stdc++6 lib32gcc1 lib32ncurses5 lib32z1 lib32z1-dev
```